# jquery mobile radio button onchange event does not fire

Tags: jquery, events, mobile, radio-button, onchange

I have implemented jquery mobile into a shopsystem which generates different radio buttons for payment methods like this:

```
<input type="radio" name="NewMethodOfPayment" onchange="openWaitScreen();jQuery('#theForm').submit();return false;" value="1000" title="PayPal" checked="checked" id="PaymentMethod1000">
```

By testing this with desktop browsers it works fine when choosing different payment methods but when using my iPhone, for example, the page reloads and the checked radio button is not checked.

I don't get it. This makes me crazy.